# hide content from mobile version of my site in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want attached lines to be displayed only on desktop version of my site in wordpress. Would you please tell me to what should I add to my code in function.php ?

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding the code as image, put the code directly in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions.php ? why just not add a simple CSS to hide on mobile devices. 
For example add this inside dashboard >> appearance >> customize >> additional css

```
`@media (max-width:980px){
   #fullScreenLayer{
      display:none!important;
     }
}`
```

P.S: change 980px according to your theme's media queries.